# how to take input from text field and use it as a variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, apple-push-notifications

i got a text_field_tag

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <%= label_tag(:my_name, "Enter the name:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:my_name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Process") %>
  <%  %>
<% end %>
```

and i got a submit button "process"

and in the same view i got this action defined

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Send notification',  controller: "home", action: "send_notification", token: device.token%></td>
```

and here is the method located in the home controller

```
def send_notification
    logger.info "Device token registrato: " + params[:token].to_s
    APNS.send_notification(params[:token].to_s, 'hello world' )
    redirect_to home_index_path, :notice => "Notification sent to device #{params[:token]}"
  end
```

what i want is this;

set the 'hello world' part with the input came from the text field.

how can i do this?

I searched for an answer but couldn't manage to find one.

Comment: What should send notification? Clicking the 'Send Notification' link or submitting the form ?

Comment: clicking the send notification or submitting the form, both of them will send notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get it from the `params`, like this:

```
def send_notification
  logger.info "Device token registrato: " + params[:token].to_s
  APNS.send_notification(params[:token].to_s, params[:my_name] )
  redirect_to home_index_path, :notice => "Notification sent to device #{params[:token]}"
end
```

Comment: Notification needs to have either a hash or string this is the error i get since it's null when i press send notification button params[:my_name] is null.How can i store it